# Omit field name when field type is interface in go struct?

Tags: go

```
type KeyRepository interface {
    GetKeys() []*rsa.PublicKey
}

type TokenParser struct {
    KeyRepository
    issuers []string
}

func NewTokenParser(keyRepository KeyRepository, issuers []string) (TokenParser, error) {
    return TokenParser{
        KeyRepository:    keyRepository,
        issuers: issuers,
    }, nil
}

func (p TokenParser) SomeOperation() {
   p.GetKeys() // ???
}
```

I am confused that, why now `GetKeys()` is implemented by `TokenParser` struct? Should not it be `p.KeyRepository.GetKeys()`? When omitting the field name and the field type is interface, we are actually implementing the interface or we are declaring a field with same name? Thanks.
Thanks.

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with the fact that the field's type is an interface type.

Comment: A field that doesn't have an explicit name is called an __embedded__ field. The methods and/or fields of an embedded field's type are __promoted__, this means that they can be accessed directly, without specifying the embedded field's name.

Comment: Search for "embedded" in [this section](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types) of the official language spec.